# Cannot Access Folder

Tags: cd-command

I downloaded this folder using

```
wget https://github.com/duxingkei33/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3
```

when I ls I can see the folder `orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3`

however when I

```
cd orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3
```

I get error:

```
-bash: cd: orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the html page at the url, not a directory. You can check it by running `cat` on that file.

Comment: So what can I run to download the folder?

Comment: Use git `git clone https://github.com/duxingkei33/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3.git`, this all is explained on github help  https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/